# Java Unable to load arabic character U+062C into PDF on PDFBox even though it exists on the font

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

The font I am using is an arial.tff. Aside from this specific character (U+062C) all the other characters seem to be working fine.

Somehow when it reaches this point it just throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+062C ('afii57420') is not available in this font Helvetica (generic: ArialMT) encoding: StandardEncoding with differences
```

Code below:

```
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(pdfDocumentTemplate, this.resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:arial.ttf").getInputStream(), false);
PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdAcroFormOptional.get();
String fontName = pdAcroForm.getDefaultResources()
                            .add(font)
                            .getName();

for (GenerateDocumentPlaceholder placeholder : command.getPlaceholderList()) {
    PDTextField field = (PDTextField) pdAcroForm.getField(placeholder.getName());
    try {
        if (field != null) {
            field.setDefaultAppearance("/" + fontName + " 0 Tf 0 g");
            field.setValue(placeholder.getValue());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error while updating field {}", placeholder.getValue(), ex);
    }
}
```

And here's the font with the character:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It's weird that it mentions "Helvetica" despite that you used Arial. Another weird thing is `.add(this.getPdfFont(pdfDocumentTemplate, font))`, why isn't this `.add(font)`?

Comment: Regarding the getPdfFont() it's a custom method, that returns the font, i forgot to edit that out when simplifying for the example, fixed it.

Comment: I first thought of PDF _embedded_ fonts, where only a part of the font was stored. Which plays havoc with PDF forms with input fields. It still would be worth looking into the PDF properties relating the used fonts.

Comment: Next thing to try would be you upload the PDF and change your code to something miminal, i.e. only changing one single field.

Comment: Another think to try, save the file after the update of the default resources, then reload for the rest of the work. I remember that there was a problm once, related to cache population, but I don't remember the details.

Comment: If I change the code to a single field it will work, it's that specific character that is not working (if I remove it from the input it will work)

Tried also saving the file after updating the default resources but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by replacing the embedded resources within pdf by doing this:

```
private String getPdfFontName(PDAcroForm pdAcroForm, PDDocument pdfDocumentTemplate, String resource) throws ConstraintViolatedException {
        String fontName = "";
        try {
            PDResources pdResources = new PDResources();
            pdAcroForm.setDefaultResources(pdResources);
            PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(pdfDocumentTemplate, this.resourceLoader.getResource(resource).getInputStream());
            pdResources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), font);
            fontName = pdResources.add(font).getName();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("Error while adding arabic font", ex);
        }
        return fontName;
    }
```

And then using it like this:

```
        String fontName = this.getPdfFontName(pdAcroForm, pdfDocumentTemplate, "classpath:Arial.ttf");

        for (GenerateDocumentPlaceholder placeholder : command.getPlaceholderList()) {
            PDTextField field = (PDTextField) pdAcroForm.getField(placeholder.getName());
            try {
                if (field != null) {
                    field.setDefaultAppearance("/" + fontName + " 0 Tf 0 g");
                    field.setValue(placeholder.getValue());
             } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.error("Error while updating field {}", placeholder.getValue(), ex);
             }
        }
```